AffiliateWP 3-Phase Payout Customization Not Showing on Referral Edit Screen
I’m trying to implement a custom three-phase payout structure for referrals in AffiliateWP Plugin on my WordPress site. The idea is that when a referral is created (e.g., from a Gravity Forms submission), it automatically sets some custom meta fields (phase_1_paid, phase_2_paid, phase_3_paid, and total_commission), and then on the referral edit screen, I can see checkboxes to manually mark each phase as paid.
What I’m Trying to Achieve:
When a new referral is created, I assign custom meta fields to represent a total commission (e.g., 50,000 Rs) and three separate payout phases (15k, 15k, 20k).
In the WordPress admin, when I edit the referral, I should see checkboxes for “Phase 1 Paid”, “Phase 2 Paid”, and “Phase 3 Paid”.
Affiliates should see a summary of these phases in their dashboard, showing which have been paid and which are pending.
I started by using the affwp_referral_created action to add meta fields to referrals. I expected that after a new referral was generated, the phase_1_paid, phase_2_paid, phase_3_paid, and total_commission meta would be set, and thus the referral edit screen would show the corresponding checkboxes defined in my code. I tried removing all conditions so that the logic applies to every referral, confirmed no PHP errors occur, and tested with newly created referrals. I also checked the snippet to ensure it only requires one argument for the edit screen action, as previously I had an argument mismatch issue. Despite these efforts, the expected checkboxes and meta-related fields don’t show up, leaving me unsure why the fields aren’t appearing at all.
The Code Used:
// 1. Initialize the 3-phase meta on referral creation
add_action( 'affwp_referral_created', 'my_initialize_three_phase_referral', 10, 2 );
function my_initialize_three_phase_referral( $referral_id, $data ) {
    affwp_update_referral_meta( $referral_id, 'phase_1_paid', 0 );
    affwp_update_referral_meta( $referral_id, 'phase_2_paid', 0 );
    affwp_update_referral_meta( $referral_id, 'phase_3_paid', 0 );
    affwp_update_referral_meta( $referral_id, 'total_commission', 50000 );
    affwp_add_referral_note( $referral_id, 'Referral initialized with a 3-phase payout structure (Total: 50,000 Rs).');
}

// 2. Add checkboxes to referral edit screen
add_action( 'affwp_edit_referral_bottom', 'my_add_phase_paid_checkboxes', 10 );
function my_add_phase_paid_checkboxes( $referral ) {
    $total_commission = affwp_get_referral_meta( $referral->referral_id, 'total_commission', true );
    if ( empty( $total_commission ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $phase_1_paid = affwp_get_referral_meta( $referral->referral_id, 'phase_1_paid', true );
    $phase_2_paid = affwp_get_referral_meta( $referral->referral_id, 'phase_2_paid', true );
    $phase_3_paid = affwp_get_referral_meta( $referral->referral_id, 'phase_3_paid', true );
    ?>
    <h3>3-Phase Payout Status</h3>
    <p>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="phase_1_paid" value="1" <?php checked( $phase_1_paid, 1 ); ?>> Phase 1 Paid (15,000 Rs)</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="phase_2_paid" value="1" <?php checked( $phase_2_paid, 1 ); ?>> Phase 2 Paid (15,000 Rs)</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="phase_3_paid" value="1" <?php checked( $phase_3_paid, 1 ); ?>> Phase 3 Paid (20,000 Rs)</label><br>
    </p>
    <?php
}

// 3. Save updated phase status on referral update
add_action( 'affwp_update_referral', 'my_save_phase_paid_fields', 10, 2 );
function my_save_phase_paid_fields( $referral_id, $data ) {
    $total_commission = affwp_get_referral_meta( $referral_id, 'total_commission', true );
    if ( empty( $total_commission ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $phases = array(
        1 => array( 'key' => 'phase_1_paid', 'amount' => 15000 ),
        2 => array( 'key' => 'phase_2_paid', 'amount' => 15000 ),
        3 => array( 'key' => 'phase_3_paid', 'amount' => 20000 )
    );

    foreach ( $phases as $num => $phase_data ) {
        $paid_val = isset( $_POST[ $phase_data['key'] ] ) ? 1 : 0;
        $current_val = affwp_get_referral_meta( $referral_id, $phase_data['key'], true );

        if ( $paid_val != $current_val ) {
            affwp_update_referral_meta( $referral_id, $phase_data['key'], $paid_val );
            if ( $paid_val == 1 ) {
                affwp_add_referral_note( $referral_id, sprintf('Phase %d payment of %d Rs marked as paid on %s.', $num, $phase_data['amount'], date('Y-m-d')) );
            } else {
                affwp_add_referral_note( $referral_id, sprintf('Phase %d payment reverted to unpaid on %s.', $num, date('Y-m-d')) );
            }
        }
    }
}


What I’ve Tried:
Removed any if conditions, so the logic applies to all referrals.
Created fresh referrals after the code was in place.
Checked that the code is placed in functions.php of a child theme, and that it’s definitely loading.
Goal:
To see the three checkboxes (Phase 1, Phase 2, Phase 3) on the Edit Referral screen so I can manually mark each phase as paid.
Ultimately, affiliates should see a breakdown of their three-phase payouts in their dashboard, but the first step is seeing these checkboxes in the admin interface.
Question:
What might I be missing or doing wrong that prevents the three-phase payout checkboxes from appearing in the referral edit screen? Any guidance on debugging the affwp_referral_created action or the referral meta would be appreciated.
